# Excel : Data Validation of Mac Address using Custom

Tags: excel

I'm new to Excel  custom data validaiton . I want to prevent users from inserting wrong mac-address format . Correct Mac-Address format which I need to allow as input  is show below :

```
aabc.1234.acbc

9978.a8f6.2c3a
```

As you know mac-add can be from number "0-9",letter a-f or A-F .  I doing some google searches I was able to do this :

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(FIND(MID(K1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(K1))),1),"0123456789abcdefABCDEF")))
```

This  validate  without the dot "." after 4 characters , however I need to check for  dot "." after 4 characters. Above  works fine  for below data :

```
aabc1234aacd

1234ac3d1209
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use AND() to do check for the `.`

Comment: Hey Scott, I tried this but it didnt work =AND(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(FIND(MID(K1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(K1))),1),"0123456789abcdefABCDEF"))),ISNUMBER(FIND(".",K1)))

Comment: `MID(k1,5,1) = "."` and add the `.` to the string in the find or it will error. `"0123456789.a‌​bcdefABCDEF"`